# Effectiveness of a glowing hot tungsten sword against medieval era knights?

Tags: science-based, magic, science-fiction, weapons, medieval

A blade made out of tungsten alloy that’s also electrically heated to 3000C. The shape and sharpness is similar to a katana.

The user carries a battery pack that provides enough energy for the sword to last about 3 hours.

The dimensions of the blade is 75cm long, 3cm wide and a thickness of 6.7mm at its thickest point.

How would it do against plate armour, chainmail and of course, bare skin?

Ps:Don’t worry about the weight there’s a guy strong enough to wield it in my universe.

I got my idea from here: 
https://youtu.be/_efVoeiSKP0

Comment: ever considered using a different metal? I'm sure something like iron or stainless steel would work much, much better,

Comment: @GreenieE.-ReinstateMonica wont that weaken or softening the steel structure ?

Comment: @GreenieE.-ReinstateMonica the blade’ll melt though.

Comment: Have you considered using your superpowered battery pack in combination with a metal cutting laser?

Comment: @Scott Whitlock What’s the range of the laser?

Comment: @Inthenameofthestory - as everyone has mentioned, tungsten is completely useless and utterly irrelevant, so forget "tungsten".   I feel the sense of your question is "if I had an incredibly hot sword-like device ...".  Simply set aside the issue of what the hell it could be made of.  For me the real sense of your question is **"how hot would this (thing made of handwavium scifi material) have to be to easily slice through stuff?"**  That's a great question!

Comment: BTW this "hype heat sword" would perhaps be some sort of *ceramic*?  IDK.  The interesting question is, how hot would it have to be?

Comment: @Fattie A scenario I was imagining: A person is backed up to a corner by a group of knights. He draws his sword, the knights laughing at him for what can a single man do against a group? Then his sword begins to glow...

Comment: @Inthenameofthestory  **I love all of this a lot** but (a) tungsten is not relevant, honest.  it would be "hyper ceramics" or some other mystery material (b) I think the fascinating science Q that some smart person on here could answer is ***what would be the temperature involved***

Comment: Just use all that power and electrocute the knight in its shiny armour. 

Comment: Before we discuss how it works on an opponent, I'd like to know whether this sword can even be built. Let's handwave the energy generation issue -- assume you have a battery that can output the massive energy needed for this sword, and assume the battery is portable. Still: What kind of wires are needed to deliver that electricity? You need something with really low resistance so the wires themselves do not melt, IIRC my college physics classes. Do we have wearable cabling that can work for this?

Comment: @SRM I got my inspiration from a hacksmith video on “proto-sabers”. He had a a rod of tungsten surrounded by titanium with a special handle that cools itself down.

Comment: I hope nobody is looking at it, you'll go blind. I once observed a test where they drained some aluminium carbide sponge from a furnace @ 2400, and I had fake images on my retina for days, even if I wore tinted glasses. (should have used welding goggles, I know). That was from 20m away, if you wave that near anyones face, I have a feeling that visual acuity of whomever is involved in the brouhaha drops rapidly

Comment: The tungsten will burn up so much of a sword left. That is why Tungsten is always used in vacuum or inert gas containers.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**It would damage itself more than the opponent.**
As other answers mentioned, Tungsten would be much too brittle to use, and shatter at the first strike(s).
If this can be overcome by changing the metal composition, you would run into different problems like heat dissapation making the handle too hot to hold.

Even if a structurally sound and handleable sword could be made with a portable battery, it wouldn't be very effective against plate armour.

Plate armour is already rivaling swords on structural integrety, rendering swords almost useless if not used as a stabbing implement. If the swords structural integrety was lowered even further by heating it up, it would have much higher chances of breaking, especially when used for stabbing.

Apart from that, a single strike from a heated sword to a plate of steel would probably not transfer enough heat quickly enough to have much effect in the first place. The time of contact is not long enough for the heat transfer, and the heat might be damaging, but would quickly be dissapated by the surrounding armour.

To add to this, it would be completely impossible to keep any kind of edge on the sword. It is already hard to not destroy the edge of a sword by hitting anything hard, especially so when the sword is weakened by heat. A single strike would roll and chip the edge blunter than a rock.

As for attacks against chain mail, this would be a bit more effective, but would still be quite damaging to the sword, and the heat would still not have much added value.

Against bare skin, a sword is a sword. It will cut. But of course hitting any kind of bone would again be damaging to the sword. The heat would actually work against you when attacking an unarmoured opponent, because it would cauturise the wound instantly, minimising blood loss. The worst problem with superficial wounds would be the n-th degree burn, while painful and damaging, this has a much larger window of being treatable than gushing blood loss.

Comment: I agree, a heated sword in general is pointless unless it's lightsaber-hot. Swords and katanas in particular are designed for slashing at enemies and inflicting blood loss.

Comment: I suggest looking into the "forged in fire" series available on YouTube. It is a smiting competition, and the weapons tests at the end will show you exactly how fragile even well made swords can be.

Comment: Indeed, over plate armour, I believe the most effective attack is actually brute strength to deliver a heavy, blunt blow, which will ideally break through the armour, or else dent it considerably. Even if neither of those take place, the force of the blow will still be felt by the person inside, even though spread over a larger area by the armour. Chain mail is a sort of "flexible plate armour", and a heavy blow would be very effective there.

Comment: @Dragongeek even “lightsaber-hot” will only help when you have the plot on your side…

Comment: @RalphBolton Typically under the armour there would be a heavy quilted coat that would insulate against a lot of heat. with a lot of luck you could have it catch fire dense linnen under armour doesn't sound easily flammable.

Answer (score 32):

Yes, you have an effective weapon here. Just throw away the useless sword and find a way to get the battery pack to release all its energy at once instead of over three hours. It contains a *lot* of energy, and will make an excellent explosive device.

Comment: Or maybe you can arrange to electrocute someone with that battery pack.

Comment: Do power a railgun, perhaps?

Comment: I think you can simply re-invent the Taser. Touch the armor with the blade, and allow the battery to discharge into the blade. Blade of Doom: kills on touch.

Comment: Indeed, if you can engineer and charge the battery, you can probably engineer all sorts of exotic looking effects and weaponry. If you can keep a tungsten stick at 3000C, why not keep a big bowl of lead solder at just 200C and fling that about at your enemies? You could probably engineer a Van-de-Graaf device to shoot lightening at your (metal clad) enemies. A whole load of lightening buzzing and cracking on the back of a cart being pushed towards a medieval soldier would probably be enough to make them turn and run - no swords required.

Comment: @EnricNaval Wear a long, metal coat between the battery pack that touches the ground - then just prod your enemy with a pole that carries the positive voltage.

Comment: That's about 50kW for emissivity 1/3 (reasonable for tungsten). Over three hours we have 540 MJ of energy. The capacity of a Tesla's ~500kg battery is 306 MJ. You have miraculous technology and/or superhuman strength!

Comment: @Joshua Electrocuting an angry person who's walking around in what's basically a personal [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) while trying to whack you with a sword is probably not very easy.  I'd rather be the guy with the sword and the Faraday cage than the guy with the battery in that fight.

Answer (score 29):

Tungsten is very brittle. So brittle that it shatters when hit.

Your warrior will be helpless on the battlefield after the first blow.

Summary: it will work very poorly.

Comment: Even with alloys?

Comment: If it's so brittle, why did they make the cores of armor piercing tank shells out of it?

Comment: @Ryan_L Because it’s very dense. It doesn’t matter if the core of an armour-piercing shell is brittle, because if it fractures the pieces will still keep going in the same direction.

Comment: @user72381 I don't know about tungsten alloys. But the key point of tungsten is, that it is much denser than any other metal of similar atomic weight. Afaik, tungsten is twice as dense as lead, even though they are close neighbors in the periodic table. Assuming you can get tungsten to alloy with another metal, I guess it will very quickly change the crystal structure such that it reduce the density of the material significantly. - That said, the key point of using steel in weapons/armor is its excellent ratio of strength to weight. Most other materials perform much worse in combat.

Comment: Check out this Taofledermaus video where they shoot a tungsten cube.  I thought it would shatter but the thing was absolutely impervious.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n5kEj5ijChc

Comment: @Ryan_L: For basically the same reason that they make bullets out of lead.  And why a lead bullet can go through steel armor.

Comment: Even if it were structurally sound, the sword would not transfer enough heat to make a difference in a fight. The only real effect it would have is lightly cauturizing wounds which would be counter productive.

Comment: @RyanL With reference to the answer, how often does an armour-piercing shell need to try for a second blow?

Comment: @Ryan_L - the badass bullet thing is purely due to **weight**, same deal with depleted uranium.  Gold is far too expensive.  That's all there is to it.  This same confusing issue arises when people think the depleted uranium has something to do with radioactivity or nuclear explosions or such.  It's just "heavy".

Comment: -1 from me. This is too simplistic. **a)** – _is_ tungsten still as brittle at 3000°C as it is at room temperature? I don't know, but I doubt it **b)** this sword has a very strong effect that's quite independent of its mechanical characteristics. It would probably not _need_ to deal out _blows_ like you would with a normal sword.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Tungsten has a ductile-to-brittle transition temperature of around 400 C. See hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/jpa-00253413/document. So at 3000 C, it will certainly not undergo brittle failure (i.e., shattering)

Comment: This isn't my area of expertise but after some web searches a) tungsten carbide alloy looks like it avoids the brittleness problem of tungsten entirely and b) @Aliden 's citation looks good that hot tungsten also avoids the brittleness problem. Tungsten carbide melts at 5,198°F / 2,870°C. So I agree with Aliden that this answer is wrong.

Comment: Still, we got to wonder what the Tungsten properties are at 3000°C. It may be ductile, but does it hold an edge? Or would you just dent your sword when you strike cold iron?

Answer (score 22):

3000C is very, very hot.  Steel forges and glassblowers operate around 1000C.  They wear protective gear just to stand near the stuff.

I know volcanologists have issues with their gear spontaneously catching fire due to the heat off of lava flows (again, roughly 1000C).  Granted, the flows are a lot bigger than this sword.  Still, I think contactless ignition would be a recurring threat.

Comment: I was thinking something like this: https://youtu.be/_efVoeiSKP0

Comment: Yep. The radiated power grows with the *fourth* power of the temperature: Twice as hot, 16 times the power output! Going from 1000°C to 3000°C you go from 1273K to 3273K, which is a factor of 2.57, which translates to a power output factor of 44x.

Comment: To add to this, I would imagine the blade would be impossible to hold. You can't have a blade of 3000°, and have no heat dissapate into the tang keeping it cool enough to handle. Touching the sword would burn your hands instantly regardless of any protective equipment.

Comment: @user72381 don't forget the guy in the video is only playing with his sword for short moments.

Comment: This is the correct answer. That sword, if you _can_ hold it at all, would probably prevent anybody from getting in melee range alive in the first place.

Comment: If you have a battery pack that can keep the sword heated like that, then you can probably create a way to hold onto the sword with an electromagnet instead of contacting it directly. Maybe you just keep it on a really long pike. Although... don't you have a problem with the wires that generate this heat also getting hot?

Comment: @SRM then you can kill the armor wearing enemies just with the electromagnet.

Comment: @Holger Maybe your opponent has EM countermeasures? There's a lot of complications around this question! I like the concept, but it needs a lot of fleshing.

Comment: @SRM “medieval era knights” with EM countermeasures? Rather unlikely…

Comment: @Holger Tech doesn't tend to stay bottled up very long. At some point, the other side will figure out what you're doing. Might be a generation, but with a good spy, it might be just a few months, depending upon how good the existing engineering background is. "We don't know what this 'electricity' stuff is, and we have no idea what their math means, but we can measure the wires on this captured armor and replicate the metals." I'm just suggesting that it's a thing that a story might develop.

Answer (score 12):

Your blade is about [150 cm^3 of tungsten, roughly 3 kg](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=75+cm+*+3+cm+*+6.7mm+of+tungsten). That's a lot of mass to heat up and maintain at 3000 K. The surface area of your sword is about 550 cm^2. More surface area will radiate away the energy faster requiring a large battery and also melting the user.

All that heat will be right near your face and hands making it possibly impossible to hold without bulky thermal protection. Even if you were, the chaos of combat might result in your arm being jostled and that 3000 C blade brushing against YOU.

And, as others have noted, it won't even work against armor.

Swords were not terribly effective on the battlefield. They required being in close combat which makes it more likely you'll get injured. They require lots of room to swing, which means your allies have to stay well away from you leaving you fighting isolated. Movies which depict battles  as a mixed brawl of individual sword battles are fantasy. Victorious ancient and medieval armies fought in tight formations. An isolated warrior is a dead warrior.

Swords are the [service pistol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_pistol) of melee combat. They were a backup weapon you use when you lose your main weapon. Or used for duels.

If the sword wasn't your main weapon, what was? The [polearm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_weapon). And the ultimate expression of the polearm was the [pike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pike_(weapon)).

***What you want is a heated pike.*** And you want a lot of them. And you probably want to scale it back to 1000 C.

Only heat the tip. It's much less mass to heat up and much smaller surface area to radiate that heat away meaning a smaller battery and potentially more pikemen. Add a bit of very high temperature insulation between the hot tip and the pole. The pole itself could be wood, good insulation, or perhaps aluminum. To protect the wiring from the battery to the tip, run it inside protected channel in the pole, or perhaps make the pole hollow. Having the heated tip at the end of a long pole keeps it well away from the user avoiding baking the user or their buddies next to them on the line.

Expecting to repeatedly bash anything at 3000 C against other things and expect to have anything but a lump of hot slag left over is ambitious. Scale it back to a [mere 1000 C](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=1000+C+knife). Use a [superalloy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superalloy) designed to hold together at that temperature. They will also be stronger, lighter, and sharper than tungsten. At the end of a pole you'll appreciate the reduced weight.

Thrusting with a sharp, light 1000 C alloy tipped pike is more likely to penetrate armor than slashing with a heavy, dull tungsten sword. Even if it doesn't penetrate it still scare the hell out of the enemy line.

Ancient and medieval warfare was a lot less stabbing and a lot more pushing, ["the awful push of pike"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_of_pike), with the goal of disrupting the enemy's formation. Even if you don't penetrate their armor, the enemy isn't going to want to confront a wall of lava-hot pikes. They will probably attempt to back away disrupting their formation and giving you victory.

[image]

Like this, but also on fire.

Comment: until the handle of your pike bursts into flames, the blade too, because metallic titanium burns in air at 600 degree , all for no benefit.

Comment: @John You'd have to make at least some of the shaft out of something other than wood (presumably the hilt of the OP's 3000 C sword isn't leather). And you'd use an alloy that doesn't burn at those temperatures. A steel alloy works just as well.

Comment: "And the ultimate expression of the polearm was the pike." Halberdiers would probably disagree.

Comment: @nick012000 Pikemen and halberdiers did disagree. Extensively. Violently.

Comment: If the alloy does not burn at those tempratures there is not enough titanium in it to call it titanium, also again it offers no benefit.

Comment: [Fire lances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_gunpowder#Fire_lance) were a thing. When people were able to develop projectile weapons from the same underlying techniques, they did so, because the "rule of cool" is lamentably ineffective in real world warfare.

Comment: @nick012000 well......... pike formation that consist of pike,halberd, zweihander and gun later become only pike and gun for a reason.

Comment: @John I've addressed your issues with the material and pole. I'm not a material scientist so I've left it at some high temperature superalloy suitable for making blades.

Answer (score 7):

As a very gross oversimplification, a knight in full armor was *battered* down, not *cut* down. That's why many knights carried a [mace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mace_(bludgeon)#European_Middle_Ages) instead of a sword. Sure, a [war hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_hammer) was used to penetrate the armor, but that was no sword, either.

Heating the sword means that a little heat is transferred on a blow, but as a gut feeling that won't be the main damaging mechanism to the armor or to the person under that armor. The contact just isn't long enough.

Comment: or pierce the armor gap, at least sword can be use to pierce or bashing, usually by half swording, or bashing using murder stroke, but the real weapon to kill knight is dagger anyway if you dont want to take prisoner since is easier to pierce the gap in the eye. i wonder will it increase overheating though, thats one of problem with full plate armor.

Answer (score 7):

Never mind its brittleness at 3000C or otherwise ...

unless your sword fights are in a perfect vacuum or a halon or noble gas atmosphere, it'll burn with the oxygen in air long before it reaches 3000K.

Anywhere tungsten is heated it is kept enveloped in inert gas - either as a lightbulb filament, in the glass envelope - or as a TIG welding rod where T refers to Tungsten, and IG refers to a plume of inert gas (often argon) around the weld.

You are now holding a hilt...

A couple of references... [confirming the glass envelope is to keep oxygen away from the filament](https://www.uu.edu/dept/physics/scienceguys/2002Aug.cfm) and [combusting tungsten wire as part of another experiment](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18961689). I still can't view even the abstract of that Springer article.
However its [MSDS (pdf) lists it as a flammable hazard](https://nj.gov/health/eoh/rtkweb/documents/fs/1959.pdf) in the powder form, but heating it to white heat doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: @Aliden Having difficulty finding something non-paywalled, other than rather chatty threads on welding fora... and https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00743115 --- can't even see teh abstract!

Comment: best to far... https://home.howstuffworks.com/light-bulb2.htm

Comment: What about this? https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00743115 It looks like there might be sufficient information on the first page

Comment: @Aliden after reading that article, I'm convinced that even without actual combustion the oxidation will be extremely problematic. Oxides of tungsten actually melt at a much lower temperature than tungsten itself, so any oxide coating that forms will slough off. Effectively the blade would oxidize continually. Swinging it around would spray molten WO everywhere, not desirable.

Answer (score 5):

The heat adds absolutely no advantage against an armored opponent.  To do damage, you'd have to hold the heated sword against the foe long enough for significant heat transfer to take place.  But the foe is encased in steel, which is a good conductor & radiator of heat, so it disperses over the piece of armor that you're hitting, with some of it radiating away.  Meanwhile the foe is most likely wearing a nice insulated gambeson https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambeson or other padding under the armor, so it will take a while for the heat to penetrate deep enough to affect him.

Bottom line: while you'll frantically trying to hold your glowing hot sword against the foe's armor (while trying to avoid your own sword :-)), he twists around, inserts his dagger in one of your armor's joints, and kills you.

Answer (score 5):

Considering tungsten's melting point is [3,422 °C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tungsten), your champion would be swinging something akin to a very hot wet noodle, so not very effective. Realize a blade in medieval times had semi-sharp edges, not to specifically cut through things, but to rather concentrate the force of the inertial energy being brought to bear by it. Even though [tungsten is quite a bit heavier in weight per cubic amount than steel](https://mojobob.com/roleplay/weight_chart.html), if the weapon is a hot noodle, it would just deform as it hit something rather than cutting through it. Your champion would be much better off just swinging a cold blade made of tungsten than they would be by swinging the hot noodle. More than likely they'd do more damage to themselves than they would their opponent.

Comment: This answer assumes exactly the opposite of the “tungsten is too brittle” ones. I'm pretty sure tungsten at 3000°C is _not_ “wet noodle” soft, nor as brittle as at room temperature, but I don't know. If you do know, add a reference to the answer. Else this answer is just speculation.

Comment: ...and, _if_ it were wet-noodle-soft, then this would actually probably make it _more_ effective, not less. Soft means more contact surface means quicker heat transfer.

Comment: You'll have contact surface *once* until it deforms out of shape. Then, as it deforms around the object, it'll get stuck. 3000 °C is ~300 °C above what would be considered *forging temperature*. Forging temperature is where it would make the metal easier to move and shape. Anything above that only makes it easier to move and softer still. This makes it an infeasible prospect. I didn't even go into the amount of energy it would take to heat and hold the blade to the temps you are describing. In a normal forge you cannot even get it to this temperature. You'd need an arc furnace for it to happen

Answer (score 4):

**TL; DR - Hot sword is better for roasting its wielder than chopping up their enemies**

Looking at this from a heat transfer perspective, this sword has some problems that are going to make it unusable. [dspeyer's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/168574/21272) notes the danger of spontaneous ignition of clothing. I'm going to address what happens to the wielder in the case where nothing spontaneously ignites. For the sake of simplicity, I'm going to treat the sword as a cylinder with a diameter of 3 cm and a height of 75 cm being held 60 cm in front of a plane 50 cm wide.

[image: Mockup of person holding sword]

Assuming the sword acts as a blackbody, it will transfer heat via thermal radiation to something at body temperature at a rate of:
$$\dot{Q}' = \pi d \sigma\left(T_{sword}^4 - T_{body}^4\right)$$
which gives a heat transfer rate of 613 kW/m. With a 75 cm long sword, we're looking at a heat output of 460 kW. This heat will be released in all directions, so looking at the fraction of a circle surrounding the sword the "body" blocks, it will only receive 1/8 of that power, or 57.8 kW.

Let's put that number in perspective. If I take 100 kg of water (which is a not-too-terrible model of your swordsman) and start putting heat into it at 57.8 kW, I can take it from body temperature (37 C) to the temperature at which death will almost certainly occur (44 C) in under a minute.

In other words, it doesn't matter how effective a weapon the sword is. It will kill its wielder before it can ever be used.

Comment: So you're basically holding 460 one-kilowatt electric radiators at arm's length...sir knight wielding it is going to need some pretty good insulation/cooling. I reckon he would blister and drop it rather than dying though :)

Answer (score 3):

Also, doing some math on that battery...

The sword is about 1000x the volume of a light bulb filament.  Assuming the energy cost is linear in volume (because I don't want to do really difficult math), this means we need 100kw.  For 3 hours, 300kwh.

Our best LiON batteries get a bit under 300wh/kg, so this will weigh a metric ton.

It would require only 30kg of gasoline, but a highly efficient fuel cell (an internal combustion engine isn't nearly efficient enough).  Also, the gasoline may ignite from being near the sword.

Or you could do it with 200 *milligrams* of reactor-grade uranium, which means you can afford to compensate for an inefficient engine by increasing the fuel 10-fold.

Or 12 *micrograms* of antimatter, which might be *easier* to build a backpack-sized reactor for.  Also much easier to blow up the entire battlefield.  On purpose or by accident.

As for 300kwh released at once as an explosion, that's 1000 hand grenades, but roughly a third the power of the smallest bombs the US air force typically drops.

Comment: Energy dissipation only scales with the surface area, not the volume. Consequently, your numbers are way off.

Comment: Yes, but actually I daresay even the surface area will be more than 1000× of a light bulb filament.

Comment: "Our best LiON batteries get a bit under 300wh/kg, so this will weigh a metric ton." The Hacksmith built one of these with a battery pack you can wear on your back; also the one they built only needed 20kW.

Answer (score 2):

Tungsten is a useless material for this application, as it's very brittle. Its more useful cousin is tungsten carbide, which is a lot tougher, but it's still very brittle compared to most steels. 
Most steels and titanium alloys get soft when heated, so if you want a heated weapon, your options are either tungsten carbide, or a super-alloy.

Inconel springs to mind, or Hastelloy. Both are trademarked though, so a "nickle super-alloy" is your best bet. There are some of the best alloys under high temperature conditions, as the get tougher with increasing temperature. However, 3000 C is definitely out of range for most materials. 1000 C is already extremely hot.

Answer (score 0):

If you could make a glowing sword people would either revere you as some kind of saint or fear you as some kind of witch and have you put to death so actually your glowing sword, back pack and whatnot would actually be the least of your worries, I'd be more inclined to use the sword to make toast...that's a win for everyone.